# Removing Ad with IAP Swift

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, iad

So I am trying to put In App Purchase in my app to remove advertisement, but my ad is in another view, and I think I am removing it the wrong way, because it is breaking exactly in the removeallAds function:

```
func removeallAds() {
    ViewController().bannerAd.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

It is giving me the following error:

Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

This is my code if you want to take a look:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class IapViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var removeAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var restorePurchase: UIButton!


    @IBAction func removeAdsAct(sender: AnyObject) {
        for product in list{
            var prodId = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodId == "com.hazeApps.removeAds"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    @IBAction func resPurchaseAct(sender: AnyObject) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        removeAds.enabled = false


        //IAP Setup
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            println("IAP is up and running")
            var productId: NSSet = NSSet(object: "com.hazeApps.removeAds")
            var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productId)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            println("enable IAPs")
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func buyProduct(){
        println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func removeallAds() {
        ViewController().bannerAd.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("Product Request")
        var myProducts = response.products

        for product in myProducts{
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }

        removeAds.enabled = true
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("Transaction restored")
        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions{
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodId = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodId{
            case "com.hazeApps.removeAds":
                println("Remove Adds")
                removeallAds()
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")

            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

        println("add payment")

        for transaction: AnyObject in transactions{
            var trans = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState{

            case .Purchased:
                println("Unlock IAP here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)

                let productId = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch productId{
                    case "com.hazeApps.removeAds":
                        println("Remove Adds")
                        removeallAds()
                    default:
                        println("IAP not setup")

                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;

            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;

            default:
                println("Default")
                break;


            }
        }
    }

    func finishTransaction(trans: SKPaymentTransaction){
        println("Finish Trans")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("Removed Trans")
    }

}
```

Other thing, I have some line of code that handle in case of wireless connections to make the bannerAd hide, If the Ad is removed from superview it might get some error in this lines?